# Filepicker.io storeUrl mimetype

Tags: filepicker.io

There doesn't seem to be a mimetype for storeUrl; the default also seems to be octet-stream; how do I convert this to image/png or some image? I tried filepicker.convert, but got back a 142 error.

P.S. Putting in debug mode, I get this url:
https://developers.filepicker.io/answers/jsErrors/142

Not very helpful :/ I figure this is in your pipeline though.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the url you're trying to store? By default we try to pull the mimetype off the "Content-Type" header of the url passed in

Comment: Hmm, images off of amazon like http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41PPHajpLgL._SL160_.jpg
Content-Type seems to be image/jpeg?